# Can I sum based on a specific cell text value?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet for tracking sales leads. Each row is a lead. One of the columns is called "Status" and the options under this column are limited to a list of 4 options, i.e. Prospect, Proposal, Closed and Dead.

Is there a way for me to easily calculate how many rows have a status of Prospect vs how many have a status of Proposal, etc? I'd like to be able to have a summary at the top of the spreadsheet that shows how many of the leads are in each Status category (i.e. how many prospects vs proposals, etc).

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you want to:

1. Make sure your data is validated (ie the user must choose one of those four options from a list so the data is clean)
2. Use a simple `COUNTIF()` statement to calculate the sum of various inputs.

Let's assume your user inputs are in `COLUMN A`

At the top of the spreadsheet (or anyplace you want to place your summary) you can write something like:

```
Column B    |  Column C
------------------------
Prospect    |  =countif(A:A,"Prospect")
Lead        |  =countif(A:A,"Lead")
```

Obviously to be more efficient, I would use cell references instead of the actual text (eg "Prospect," "Lead," etc) to define your criteria.

Example of using a cell reference rather than text: `=countif(A:A,B2)`

Answer (score 2):

A pivot table may suit your expressed requirement - and possibly many others also:

Add a column label to your data, if not already present, select it and your data, Data > Pivot table report..., Add field to **Rows** and Add field to **Values**. Ensure that the **Values** field is `Summarise by: COUNTA` (there is a little down arrow to click if necessary).

Copy the pivot table into the sheet above your data:

[image: WA33974 example]